# how can i put dummy email and password inside of node js code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email, authentication

when I try to log in I have an error message "No registered admin found". I know it's because of no existing admin info. now I want to insert a dummy email and password for the admin's login how can I put that?
I'm new to this react and nodejs, please anyone can help me?

this is my code:

```
import { hash } from "../../../core/crypto/hash.js";
import { webToken } from "../../../core/crypto/web_token.js";
import { errors } from "../../../core/classes/errors.js";

import { adminsService } from "../../admins/index.js";

export const adminLogin = async (creds) => {

try {
   const admin = await adminsService.getWithCredentials(
    creds.email.toLowerCase()
   );

if (!admin) {
  throw new errors.Authentication("No registered admin found", "Auth");
}

if (!(await hash.verify(creds.password, admin.password))) {
  throw new errors.Authentication("Password doesn't match.", "Auth");
}

const token = webToken.generate({ uid: admin.id, role: "admin" }, "10h");

return { name: admin.name, email: admin.email, token };
 } catch (error) {
  throw error;
  }
 };
```

this is the problem:

```
authentication No registered admin found
Authentication {
   type: 'authentication',
   message: 'No registered admin found',
   from: 'Auth'
 }
```

Comment: I think I haven't understood your question. Do you want the admin user ? Or do you want to create a new admin user when there aren't any admin users ? If you can explain more comprehensive maybe I can help you

Comment: @Halil I need to log in as an admin without a registered admin. I don't know how can I put a dummy login email and password

Comment: @Halil I just need to put a temporary email and password for log in

Comment: Haven't you connection the database ? Is it correct for you you use normal admin user instead of dummy ? Or you define a particular email then you can login as admin with particular email. Sorry I can't think of anything else

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I need to log into my admin dashboard without registering. when I encounter a comment showing there's no registered admin found, I need to put a temporary email and password to check the flow of the login page. how can I code put email and password inside of node js code?

Comment: you probably want to use an environment variable, and *dont commit* the file that contains the environment variable. The same pattern you would use for secrets, API keys, etc. IE: develop.env contains: ADMIN_USERNAME =<yourusername> ADMIN_PASS=<yourpass>. Note: this can be done with regular JS objects too. .env is just how the dotenv package in js works.

Comment: added as answer, if it helps you please mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably want to use an environment variable, and you dont want to commit the file that contains the environment variable. The same pattern you would use for secrets, API keys, etc.

IE make new file: `develop.env`
contains:

```
ADMIN_USERNAME={yourusername}
ADMIN_PASS={yourpass}
```

then add develop.env to .gitignore so its never committed and nobody sees your details. This file will exist on the server in a production environment, for now it can rest on your local machine.

Note: this can be done with regular JS objects too. .env is just how the dotenv package in js works. https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv